# Chart.js move x axis labels to the right

Tags: chart.js

I'm using the latest chart.js to draw a simple [histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqXgW.png).
The histogram is fine but I actually need the x labels to be between the borders of every bar like this [histogram_right_labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUcNM.png), are there any methods to approach this?
I've tried `offsetGridLines: true` and `offsetGridLines: false`, but what they actually did is moving the grid lines and not the labels, unlike what I read about their actual behaviors, I think it might be a conflict in my option settings but I don't know which, any help would be appreciated.

```
options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 10,
                right: 25,
                top: 25,
                bottom: 0
            }
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    //display: false,
                    drawBorder: false,
                    padding: 20,
                    offsetGridLines: true
                },
                ticks: {           
                    beginAtZero: true,              
                }
            }],

            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    padding: 10,
                },
                gridLines: {
                    color: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
                    zeroLineColor: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
                    drawBorder: false,
                    borderDash: [2],
                    zeroLineBorderDash: [2]
                }
            }],
        },
        legend: {
            labels: {
                boxWidth: 20
            },
            display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
            backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
            bodyFontColor: "#858796",
            titleMarginBottom: 10,
            titleFontColor: '#6e707e',
            titleFontSize: 14,
            borderColor: '#dddfeb',
            borderWidth: 1,
            xPadding: 15,
            yPadding: 15,
            displayColors: false,
            intersect: false,
            mode: 'index',
            caretPadding: 10,
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a second x-axis of `type: 'linear'` as follows.

```
{
  type: 'linear',
  ticks: {
    min: 0,
    max: labels.length,
    stepSize: 1,
    callback: (v, i) => i == 0 ? '' : labels[i - 1]
  }
}
```

> Note that I use a [ticks callback method](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats) in order to provide the desired tick label at given index.

Then you should also hide the grid lines and ticks of the default x-axis.

```
{
  gridLines: {
    display: false
  },
  ticks: {
    display: false
  }
}
```

Please take a look at below runnable sample code and see how it works.

```js
const labels = ['4.80', '9.60', '14.40', '19.20', '24.00', '28.80'];

new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: "My Dataset",
      data: [4, 8, 5, 7, 2, 4],
      backgroundColor: 'orange',
      categoryPercentage: 1,
      barPercentage: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            display: false
          }
        },
        {
          type: 'linear',
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: labels.length,
            stepSize: 1,
            callback: (v, i) => i == 0 ? '' : labels[i - 1]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Worked miraculously! Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score -2):

you can use this to put the tooltips to the right. Possibilities are top, left, right and bottom

```
options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            position: 'right'
        }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately from the [official document](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/title.html), this is regarding to the title of the chart which doesn't exist, my question was regarding to the labels, thanks for the effort though.